# Why did my reputation drop down by -6?

Tags: support, reputation

Can someone help me understand what is the reason behind this drop in reputation in my Stack Overflow account please?

[image]

Comment: Questions have been deleted which you had received points from suggesting edits.

Comment: 3 posts you suggested edits for were deleted. As a result the +2 reputation points you gained for each edit were removed again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh and Martijn. I thought it was a mistake on my part. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three of the posts you made suggested edits for were deleted. As a result of that, the two reputation points you gained for each edit were removed. According to [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> - a post where you had successfully suggested an edit has been deleted: -2